# Cross domain issues accessing Excel Services in a Sharepoint App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, excel-services

I have an Sharepoint app hosted at:

```
https://app-xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site/
```

And I want to retrieve the json representation of an excel document using the Excel Service Rest API hosted at:

```
https://app.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx
```

I can't simply perform a get due to same-origin policy limitations as they are hosted on different domains, so my questions are:

1) Is this scenario even possible?

I've seen a number of post suggesting that it isn't ie:

http://techmikael.blogspot.fi/2013/07/how-to-copy-files-between-sites-using.html

2) If is is possible, how?

Comment: I assume this is a SharePoint hosted app (as opposed to provider hosted)?

Comment: As a follow up, we ended up building a custom hosted proxy to get around the lack of CORS support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't currently appear possible :(

I've tried setting up everything using `SP.RequestExecutor` in the [cross-domain library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927(v=office.15).aspx), but since the `ExcelRest.aspx` page is in the `_vti_bin` virtual directory you can't access the endpoint that way.

I've also tried using the [web proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179895(v=office.15).aspx) and specifying my host site as an authorized endpoint but I still recieve `403 -- Forbidden` responses from the server.

As an interesting, semi-related, note: it seems that app webs do not allow you to access their own `/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx` endpoint either, also responding with `403`

And here is another [link to an MSDN question with an accepted answer from MVP Steve Curran](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d737bd98-eb47-4d33-876a-564105a5f2b3/access-excel-rest-api-from-sharepoint-hosted-app?forum=appsforsharepoint) stating that this doesn't appear to work also...

Hopefully this is a scenario will be possible sometime in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?:

> By default, cross-domain workbook and data connection access is not allowed. To allow workbooks in trusted file locations (and data connections in trusted data connection libraries) to be accessed across domains by web parts, pages, or Web services, run the Stsadm.exe command-line utility, as shown in the following example, where SSP name is the name of your Excel Services Shared Services Provider:
>
> stsadm.exe -o Set-EcsSecurity -Ssp  -AllowCrossDomainAccess true|false